# Dynamic library injection fails in iOS enterprise app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, dyld

I develop enterprise apps and one of the key feature that we depend on is dynamic library injection. Until iOS 7 everything was fine. But in iOS 8 when I try to inject a dynamic library and resign using an enterprise certificate then the app crashes. When i resign the app using developer certificate then it works fine in iOS 8. And this happens only in iPhone 4s but works fine in iphone 5, 5s and iPad. Can someone shed some light on this issue.

Comment: any luck finding a solution to this issue?

Comment: No, Will post the solution here when I find it

Comment: can you share how you injected dynamic library to enterprise apps

Comment: kindly share how u do dynamic lib injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out, because the error messages were so cryptic, and nothing I searched for seemed to help.

The solution is to revoke your production certificate and regenerate it (you will need to refresh all of your other provisioning profiles that use it).  There is some data that iOS 8 needs which was missing in older versions of the certificate (even though they appear to be completely valid on the apple developer site).

This link clued me into the solution:

https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/